# Can't get a class extended on JPanel to show within a JFrame class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to create a modular MVC swing app. So i have a `Main` class that runs the code, a `Frame` class (extendeds `JFrame`) that represents the window, and within it there's a class (extendeds `JPanel`) that has my GUI elements. My aim is to be able to easily update/repaint the `Panel` class, when the View needs to change.

However, as my code is right now, it runs without errors, and it opens an empty Frame but the elements within the JPanel class won't show and I don't know why. - most probably a noob mistake, i know, but I can't see it any more.

So here's my main class:

```
package mvc;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Frame();
    }
}
```

Here's the JFrame class

```
package mvc;

import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame{
    private static int width = 500;
    private static int height  = 500;

    public Frame(){

        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        Panel game  = new Panel();      
        pane.add(game);     
        pack();

        setSize(width, height);
        setLocation(100,100);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and here's the JPanel

```
package mvc;

import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel {
    private JButton b1;
    private JLabel l1;

    public Panel(){
        Container pane = new JPanel();
        b1 = new JButton("Button");
        pane.add(b1);
        l1 = new JLabel("Label for the button");
        pane.add(l1);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing this...

```
public Panel(){
    Container pane = new JPanel();
    b1 = new JButton("Button");
    pane.add(b1);
    l1 = new JLabel("Label for the button");
    pane.add(l1);
}
```

But you're not adding `pane` to anything, so nothing is been shown on the screen

It'd be easier to just do something like...

```
public Panel(){
    b1 = new JButton("Button");
    add(b1);
    l1 = new JLabel("Label for the button");
    add(l1);
}
```

You should also be creating and modifying your UI's only from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, have a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: Ok, yes, that makes a lot of sense. The thing was that my now Panel (in the app that i'm making, not this particular example) was before extending a JFrame, and was working fine, getting the Content pane was important then, but then I had to transform it into a JPanel so i can easily update it from the View, without touching the Frame itself.